# upgrading from node 14x to 18x on server

Tags: node.js, upgrade

I have a node js project running in node v14.17.2 and it time to upgrade i thought v18.13.0
and im really afraid that something will break on the server once i change the version
to run it localy i needed to change `npm istanll` to `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`
and then to do :

```
npm install node-sass --legacy-peer-deps
npm rebuild node-sass
npm audit fix --legacy-peer-deps
```

so if ill add these steps my app  should be fine? is there any other things i need to do befor upgrading the version?
pre-upgraded pacakge.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "1.1.8",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/moment": "1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "3.0.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "3.0.1",
    "@nivo/core": "^0.73.0",
    "@nivo/pie": "^0.73.0",
    "auth0-lock": "11.30.2",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "3.1.1",
    "axios": "0.21.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "1.19.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.14.0",
    "downshift": "6.1.3",
    "formsy-react": "2.2.5",
    "jodit-react": "^1.1.1",
    "jss": "^9.8.7",
    "jss-extend": "6.2.0",
    "jss-rtl": "^0.3.0",
    "jwt-decode": "3.1.2",
    "keycode": "2.2.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "material-ui-pickers": "^2.2.4",
    "mobile-detect": "1.4.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "path-to-regexp": "6.2.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.4.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5",
    "prismjs": "1.23.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "qs": "6.10.1",
    "raw-loader": "4.0.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-autosuggest": "10.1.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "0.33.5",
    "react-chartjs-2": "2.7.4",
    "react-cookie": "^4.0.3",
    "react-credit-cards": "^0.8.3",
    "react-dnd": "14.0.2",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "14.0.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-facebook-pixel": "^1.0.4",
    "react-google-charts": "^3.0.15",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-jss": "^8.6.1",
    "react-number-format": "4.6.3",
    "react-popper": "2.2.5",
    "react-redux": "7.2.4",
    "react-rnd": "^10.3.7",
    "react-router-config": "5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.1",
    "react-select": "4.3.1",
    "react-signature-canvas": "^1.0.6",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.14.0",
    "react-table": "^6.8.6",
    "react-text-mask": "5.4.3",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.0",
    "redux": "4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "typeface-roboto": "1.1.13",
    "velocity-react": "1.4.3",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "python ../prebuild.py src/myConstants.js",
    "start": "yarn run build-css-helpers && cross-env PORT=3001 react-scripts start",
    "build": "yarn run build-css-helpers && cross-env NODE_PATH=src react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build",
    "build-css-helpers": "./node_modules/.bin/tailwind build ./src/styles/fuse-helpers.tailwind.css -c ./tailwind.js -o ./src/styles/fuse-helpers.css && postcss --use autoprefixer -o ./src/styles/fuse-helpers.css ./src/styles/fuse-helpers.css",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_PATH=src react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "cross-env NODE_PATH=src react-scripts eject",
    "build-docs": "babel-node src/main/content/components/material-ui/build.js",
    "postbuild": "python postbuild.py"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.14.5",
    "autoprefixer": "9.1.5",
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "js-beautify": "1.14.0",
    "marked": "2.1.1",
    "postcss-cli": "8.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "0.6.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.17.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

i know i have pacakges to upgrqade i want to start just with node

Comment: could you share you pre-upgrade package.json?

Comment: did in the question

Comment: Node is a runtime environment for JavaScript, so in that sense, a newer version of Node should be able to interpret older JavaScript (to certain extent). But from the details of your question I suspect what you have is a ReactJS project... Are your first upgrading and testing locally? If so, anything you replicate on the server should be fine.

Comment: i did the upgrade locally and i hade some errors then i change and added the commands i wrote in the question and only then the build worked

Comment: Do your tests still work?

Comment: you should add those errors to the question, otherwise it will be hard to find the problem